# How can I fix this "reference grid" of objects done in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript

I am attempting to make a 3x3 grid of "block" objects in JavaScript, each of which contains a reference to the blocks next to it through 4 directional parameters "below," "left," "above," and "right." The problem is due to the nature of JavaScript's object construction, I get a lot of undefined "block" references in the first blocks to be defined.

Here is a visualization of what I am trying to accomplish:

```
    [00][01][02]
    [10][11][12]
    [20][21][22]
```

Here is my code:

```
    // Block variable declarations

    var block00;
    var block01;
    var block02;

    var block10;
    var block11;
    var block12;

    var block20;
    var block21;
    var block22;

    // Block object constructor

    function block(below, left, above, right){
        this.below = below;
        this.left = left;
        this.above = above;
        this.right = right;
    }

    // Row 1

    block00 = new block(block10, null, null, block01);
    block01 = new block(block11, block00, null, block02);
    block02 = new block(block12, block01, null, null);

    // Row 2

    block10 = new block(block20, null, block00, block11);
    block11 = new block(block21, block10, block01, block12);
    block12 = new block(block22, block11, block02, null);

    // Row 3

    block20 = new block(null, null, block10, block21);
    block21 = new block(null, block20, block11, block22;
    block22 = new block(null, block21, block12, null);
```

So, for example, calling

```
    block00.below
```

will return an undefined value, but I want it to return block10.

Thanks!

Comment: On the line that begins `block00 =`, you use `block10` and `block01`, but you don't assign a value to `block10` or `block01` until later. At the time you use them they haven't been assigned a value, so their value is `undefined`. Assigning a value to them later on doesn't change the fact that they were `undefined` when you passed their values to `block()`.

Comment: You really should use arrays and loops, even if it's something "small and simple" as a 3x3 grid.

Comment: To expand on Jordan's comment, you'll have to create the objects first, then assign the references between them. (And I'd use an array of arrays and a nested for loop, not individual `blockXY` variables.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll need to construct the objects before you assign reference to them. There's no way around that.

An easy way to do that is to remove the `below` and `right` parameters from your constructor, and set those fields dynamically when that block is constructed:

```
function block(left, above) {
    this.below = null;
    this.left = left;
    this.above = above;
    this.right = null;

    if (left) left.right = this;
    if (above) above.below = this;
}
```

Comment: @robert: Thanks for the correct suggestion, although a comment would've been more appropriate.